# How to pass psql variable to DECLARE section of PL/pgSQL code?

Tags: postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, psql, postgresql-9.2

I want to use an extra var in the declare section of PL/pgSQL code in PostgreSQL.

```
DO $ANONYMOUS_BLOCK$ declare
   user_c cursor is
   select username
   from   users
   where upper(:v1) in ('ALL',upper(component_id)) order by username;
begin
   /* data */
end $ANONYMOUS_BLOCK$;
```

Shell command:

```
psql -f test.psql -v v1='SR'
```

I tried multiple cases to get the value 'SR' in above function but couldn't achieve it.

Expected result:

```
DO $ANONYMOUS_BLOCK$ declare
   user_c cursor is
   select username
   from   users
   where upper('SR') in ('ALL',upper(component_id)) order by username;
begin
   /* data */
end $ANONYMOUS_BLOCK$;
```

Need to get 'SR' value in the place of `v1`.

I get this error:

> ```
> psql:test.psql:13: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
> LINE 5:    where  :v1 in ('ALL',upper(component_id)) order by userna...
> ```

Answer (score 2):

[The manual for psql:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-)

> Variable interpolation will not be performed within quoted SQL literals and identifiers.

The body of a `DO` statement (or function) **is** a quoted literal. Dollar-quoted in this case, but all the same.

I had to give the same negative reply in this recent answer on dba.SE:

- [How to pass variable to PL/pgSQL code from the command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240542/3684)

**But** there are various workarounds, and I supplied some over there.

An easy one for your case might be to create a **temporary function** instead of the `DO` statement, and call it right away. Then you can easily pass variables. Write this to your file `test.psql`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.foo(_v1 text)
  RETURNS void AS  -- can also return sth. (as opposed to DO)
$func$
DECLARE
   user_c cursor is
   SELECT username
   FROM   users
   WHERE  upper(_v1) IN ('ALL', upper(component_id))
   ORDER  BY username;
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', _v1;  -- to demonstrate
   -- more
END 
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT pg_temp.foo(:'v1'); -- call with psql variable interpolation
```

Then call it from psql or directly from the shell:

Linux shell:

```
psql -f '\path\to\file\test.psql' -v v1='SR'
```

Windows shell:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql" -p 5432 -U postgres -f "C:\path\to\file\test.psql" -v v1='SR'
```

Adapt file paths and connection parameters to your setup.

Aside: [postgresql-9.2](/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.2), seriously? Unsupported since 2017. [Consider upgrading to a current version.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: Hi,
Upgraded version to 11.1 .
Getting below error, once after updating the psql code.
Error: schema "pg_temp" does not exist