# Migration script needs temporary variables to hold values from select statements

Tags: postgresql

I need to do the following in postgres, is this possible?
(below is what I used to do in sql server)

```
DECARE @user1 AS UUID
DECARE @user2 AS UUID
DECARE @user3 AS UUID

SELECT @user1 = id from users where type='role1'
SELECT @user2 = id from users where type='role2'
SELECT @user3 = id from users where type='role3'

IF @user1 IS NOT NULL AND @user2 IS NOT NULL AND @user3 IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    // do something here
END
```

These variables @user1, @user2, and @user3 only last as long as this migration script runs, they do not persist.

how can I do the above in postgres 14.x?

Comment: Do you actually mean "in psql" - the default comman-line terminal, which has variables and interpolation of its own. Or "in Postgres" - from any generic client? If so, can you wrap the whole migration in a single function / procedure / DO statement? Or does it have to be a generic SQL script? Either way, declare your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter using postgres version 14.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can wrap it all in a single **PL/pgSQL code block** (implicitly a single transaction) in a function, procedure, or a `DO` command - see:

- [Does a procedure run in a transaction in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250376/does-a-procedure-run-in-a-transaction-in-postgresql/28251922#28251922)

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _user1 uuid;
   _user2 uuid;
   _user3 uuid;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _user1 id FROM users WHERE type = 'role1';
   SELECT INTO _user2 id FROM users WHERE type = 'role2';
   SELECT INTO _user3 id FROM users WHERE type = 'role3';

   IF (_user1, _user2, _user3) IS NOT NULL THEN
      -- do something here
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

Note that `(user1, user2, user3) IS NOT NULL` only passes if all nested values are not null. See:

- [Why is IS NOT NULL false when checking a row type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350232/why-is-is-not-null-false-when-checking-a-row-type/27353191#27353191)

If you need session-local **variables for plain SQL**, see:

- [User-defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)

If you actually meant the command-line **terminal psql**, see:

- [How to pass parameters to sql script via psql \i command](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300281/3684)
- [How to pass psql variable to DECLARE section of PL/pgSQL code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164341/how-to-pass-psql-variable-to-declare-section-of-pl-pgsql-code/58210384#58210384)
- [Difference between set, \set and \pset in psql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593908/difference-between-set-set-and-pset-in-psql/29594391#29594391)